# Не получается парсить значение у тега span

Tags: javascript, python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Я  много вариантов использовал ну они не подходят для данной задачи,
Я хочу парсить цены в мвидео, но тег span возвращает пустой словарь, везде span мешает можете помочь какой нибудь фрагмент кинуть.
(python selenium)

[image: span]

Answer (score 1):

Можно такими способами

```js
//Пример через jQuery
console.log($("span").text().replace(/[₽\s]/ig, ""))

//native
console.log(document.querySelector("span").innerText.replace(/[₽\s]/ig, ""))

//native
console.log(document.querySelector("span").textContent.replace(/[₽\s]/ig, ""))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-sel="new_comparison-div-price_current-30053318" itemprop="price" class="fl-product-tile-price__current">
                                                    24&nbsp;990 ₽
                                                    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUB">
                                                </span>
```